# Control Keep Me Signed In (KMSI) with Microsoft Identity in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I've implemented Microsoft Identity in a .NET 5 application. I want the user to always be prompted to log in to the app whenever a challenge occurs, hence the following code:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            options.CallbackPath = ...
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = c =>
            {
                c.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        })
```

This works as expected. Is there a property (outside of the tenant-wide option) to also disable the KMSI prompt that still occurs? I went through each of the properties off of the root but it wasn't clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please refer this article to 
[Configure KMSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/keep-me-signed-in#configure-kmsi).